# itertools.product() return value

Tags: python, list, tuples

When I tried running the following code

```
product([1,2,3],['a','b'])
```

it returned an object of the following type:

```
<itertools.product object at 0x01E76D78>
```

Then I tried calling list() on it and I got the following:

```
[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b')]
```

Is there any way to make it into a list of lists, instead of tuples? Like this:

```
[[1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [2, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'a'], [3, 'b']]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It returns the cartesian product.

Comment: What is your question? Are you wondering what `itertools.product` returns? Or are you wondering how to convert the return value into a list of lists?

Comment: Why is it you need to do this? It seems very likely that whatever you are trying to achieve can be done in a better way.

Comment: `itertools` are there to avoid building lists.

Comment: Are lists worse than tuples? I was trying to convert tuples into lists because I need to format them for something else. I want to know both what itertools.product returns, and how to convert them into lists. Sorry for the ambiguity

Comment: A further question to the above asked question. how does one call each element from the returned value in the above-asked question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
list(map(list, product([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b'])))
```

The outermost `list()` is not necessary on Python 2, though it is for Python 3. That is because in Python 3 a `map object` is returned by `map()`.

Comment: This is why I think a list comprehension is better for this being cross-compatible although it is a very odd task.

Comment: @jamylak: Yes, it'd indeed be more cross-compatible. The reason I avoided them is that I generally avoid them if I don't actually *need* their dummy variables, to avoid introducing noise. (`map(list, ...)` reads a lot better to me than `[list(l) for l in ...]`... YMMV)

Comment: @Mehrad I see your point but in this case your solution would look better on Python 2 but worse in Python 3

Comment: @jamylak: I guess I missed replying to this 3 years ago, but the problem is that in Python 2 the dummy variable can affect the rest of the program since its scope leaks. It's a correctness thing not just an aesthetic thing.

Comment: What are you referring to?

Comment: @jamyla: I'm referring to your last reply; I'm saying that it's more than a readability issue; in Python 2 the list comprehension's dummy variable can reassign another variable of the same  name in the current function.

Comment: Then I don't agree with you because that applies to every use of a list comprehension. You're basically saying don't ever use a list comprehension because you may accidentally use the same variable name which will leak into the scope. Most people will just use a different descriptive name for everything anyway. This is not a valid reason to avoid using list comprehensions in Python 2

Comment: @jamylak: That's exactly what I'm saying, yeah. :P I think it is but it's okay haha.

Answer (score 2):

It returns an iterator of tuples.  If you want a list of lists, you can do:

```
[list(a) for a in product([1,2,3],['a','b'])]
```

However, in many cases, just using the iterator is better.  You can just do:

```
for item in product([1,2,3],['a','b']):
    # do what you want with the item
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following but it is pointless. Since the values do not change a tuple is more suited to this than a list. It also saves memory.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [list(x) for x in product([1,2,3],['a','b'])]
[[1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [2, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'a'], [3, 'b']]
```