# How to use list comprehension for the following code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to do the following using list comprehension

```
ans = []
for i in range(0, x):
    l = []
    for j in range(0, y):
        l.append(i*j)
    ans.append(l)
```

Comment: What did you try, and how was it deficient?

Comment: I tried the following things:`
ans = [i*j for i in range(0,x) l = [] for j in range(0,y)]
ans = [ans[i:i+y] for i in range(0, len(ans), y)]
`

Comment: Your code seems ok, too. How does it not work?

Comment: you should search for your question on SO. if you didnt find a match then you can ask the Question.

Comment: @justhalf It worked but I  couldn't figure out how to do it using list comprehension

Comment: @basilisk Yeah i tried but didn't get any significant answer so I asked.. Again, will note this point

Comment: @Vinay Sorry but I don't think you made a good search because this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633140/nested-for-loops-using-list-comprehension explain clearly what you want to do and how the answer should be. The Community can help you reach your answer but it would be very bad for you if the Community will do your homework. in this way you ll learn nothing. I'm trying to help you here. I promise it would be better if you tried to learn on yourself it will pay back in the future. very soon ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a list comprehension that is equivalent to your nested loops:

```
a = [[i * j for j in range(0, y)] for i in range(0, x)]
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer.. Don't know how it got downvotes.

Comment: I'm also not sure. Most likely people getting angry at bad questions getting answers (from higher rep users?).

Answer (score -1):

Since you want individual list:

```
ans = [[i*j for j in range(y)] for i in range(x)]
```

If you want it flattened:

```
ans = [i*j for i in range(x) for j in range(y)]
```

Comment: yeah i knew about the flattening of list.. thanx

Comment: You should have posted what you have tried as well, to avoid those downvotes.

Comment: Will surely remember to do so next time.