# How do loops work in list assignments in python?

Tags: python, list, loops

Consider the following command:

```
elite_states  = [s for i in range(len(states_batch)) 
                if rewards_batch[i]>=reward_threshold for s in states_batch[i]]
```

I found that is equivalent to the following loop:

```
_l=[]
for i in range(len(states_batch)):
  for s in states_batch[i]:
    if rewards_batch[i]>=reward_threshold:
      _l.append(s)
```

However I don't get how the loop after `s` in the first command becomes the outer loop in its equivalent. I want to understand the format of the command so I get how it works!

Comment: It may seem backwards at first, but having the last loop in the list comprehension be the inner loop is so `i` is in scope. Try ordering them the other way around, the use of `i` would come before its declaration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633140/nested-for-loops-using-list-comprehension

Comment: if you think about it they _(the correct version of the loop as stated by @ForceBru)_ are in the same order: outerloop -> if -> innerloop, the only thing that changes is the position of the result 's'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found that is equivalent to the following loop:

It isn't. List comprehensions are read in the same way as ordinary nested loops. First you loop over `range(len(states_batch))`, then, *inside this loop*, you check `if rewards_batch[i]>=reward_threshold`, next, *inside this condition*, the last loop is ran.

So the "expanded" version looks like this:

```
_l=[]
for i in range(len(states_batch)):
  if rewards_batch[i]>=reward_threshold:  # `if` and the inner `for` are switched
    for s in states_batch[i]:
      _l.append(s)
```

In code, this is extremely similar to the comprehension:

```
_l = [
  s
  for i in range(len(states_batch))
  if rewards_batch[i]>=reward_threshold
  for s in states_batch[i]
]
```

The only difference is that loops in comprehensions are written sequentially (one *after* the other), but in the expanded version they become nested one *inside* the other, the last loop in the comprehension being nested the deepest.