# How to create a pandas DataFrame from sets of items that includes all combinations of the sets?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have sets of strings, from which I need to construst the main indicator variable columns in a DataFrame. Is there a way to do this dimension expansion in Python pandas?

E.g. if I have these two sets:

```
los = set(["abc", "def"])
his = set(["X", "Y", "Z"])
```

I want to get as a result a DataFrame that includes all the combinations of the sets. Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"los": ["abc", "abc", "abc", "def", "def", "def"], "his": ["X", "Y", "Z", "X", "Y", "Z"]})
```

Ideally, I'd like this to be easily generalizable to an arbitrary number of sets.

Comment: What do you expect the output dataframe to look like?  Do you want 'los' & 'his' as column headings? In the case you have provided, since the number of combinations of los exceed the number of combinations of his, the length of columns will be different.  Do you want the excess rows to be filled with NaN or empty string?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your point? The resulting DataFrame is as I have stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the python built-in `itertools.product` to do this very easily:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

los = set(["abc", "def"])
his = set(["X", "Y", "Z"])

data = itertools.product(los, his)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["los", "his"])

print(df)
   los his
0  def   Z
1  def   X
2  def   Y
3  abc   Z
4  abc   X
5  abc   Y
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. I liked the MultiIndex approach by @political_scientist too, but your solution was three times faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.product` for this:

```
In [1308]: import itertools
In [1312]: x, y = [], []

In [1314]: for i,j in itertools.product(los,his):
      ...:     x.append(i)
      ...:     y.append(j)
      ...: 

In [1315]: x
Out[1315]: ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'def', 'def', 'def']

In [1316]: y
Out[1316]: ['Z', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'Y']
```

Then you can create your df like this:

```
In [1318]: df = pd.DataFrame({'los': x, 'his': y})

In [1319]: df
Out[1319]: 
   los his
0  abc   Z
1  abc   X
2  abc   Y
3  def   Z
4  def   X
5  def   Y
```

Answer (score 1):

A nested for loop should generate your data

```
los = set(["abc", "def"])
his = set(["X", "Y", "Z"])

a = []
b = []
for i in los:
    for j in his:
        a.append(i)
        b.append(j)
```

results in

```
a = ['def', 'def', 'def', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc']
b = ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

If you want it in dictionary format:

```
d = {}
d['los'] = a
d['his'] = b
```

A more pythonic way to do it would be via list comprehension. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633140/nested-for-loops-using-list-comprehension) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [pandas.MultiIndex.from_product](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html). This way you don't need to import `itertools`:

```py
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([los, his], names=['los', 'his']).to_frame(index=False)
```