# Nested for loop into list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I want to create the following into a list comprehension:

```
scores = []
for x in df1_names:
    for y in df2_names:
        score = fuzz.ratio(x,y)
scores.append(score)
```

I have attempted the following, but I am not sure where to include the `fuzz.ratio`.

```
matrix = [[x for x in df1_names] for y in df2_names]
```

Comment: Your indentation seems to be off. So your expected output is a matrix of all combinations, i.e., `[[fuzz.ratio(x,y) for x in df1_names] for y in df2_names]`?

Comment: Indeed a matrix with all possible combinations

Comment: Your code is equivalent to the list comprehension `scores = [fuzz.ratio(x,y) for x in df1_names for y in df2_names]`.

Comment: Sorry, this is the correct duplicate, not the one I linked above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633140/nested-for-loops-using-list-comprehension